# Can we use Elasticsearch SQL to insert or update data?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am playing with Elasticsearch SQL to query data using the familiar SQL syntax. 
Is it possible to use the same SQL syntax for data manipulation like inserts/ updates/ deletes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No,supported commands are listed here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.2/sql-commands.html

As if operation like update seems to be simple, in fact for complex model (like a document with nested fields, children...) the sql syntax wouldnot be usefull to make these kings of operation.